# Prebid.js DFP How they work together

Tags: google-dfp, prebid.js

I'm kinda a newbie at header bidding and prebid but I am trying to understand how prebid and DFP work together. Does prebid do its auction when the page loads and then after that it goes to DFP to see if it has any better ads to serve? Then whatever ad is suppose to be rendered it will ultimately be rendered by prebid onto the page?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

[Prebid.js](http://www.prebid.org) works by updating targeting(key/values) before the page requests ads from [GPT](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/).

Here is how the flow might go:

- Initialize GPT, making sure to disable initial load.
- Setup each Ad slot for GPT with information about the ad, like the allowable size
- Setup each Ad slot for Prebid creating AdUnits for them.
- Make call to Prebid to start the auction
- Wait for Prebid to notify you of the end of auction, some of the bids comeback might timeout
- Update slot targeting with parameters with the results of the header bidding auction (using pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync()).
- Call GPT to refresh the ads slots affected by the auction
- DFP will use the information in the targeting for potentially displaying header bidding ads that have a higher priority than the ads that would have been displayed

Prebid.js has bid adapters for a number of [SSPs](https://adexchanger.com/yield-management-tools/defining-ssps-ad-exchanges-and-rubicon-project/) these are used to abstract bid logic because each adapter requires different setup information.
You must setup relationships which each of this SSPs, they will tell what parameters to send them and how to setup line items in DFP.

Here is example of the data prebid returns Prebid.js 

`{
  "/9968336/header-bid-tag-0": {
    "hb_bidder": "rubicon",
    "hb_adid": "13f44b0d3c",
    "hb_pb": "1.50"
  },
  "/9968336/header-bid-tag-1": {
    "hb_bidder": "openx",
    "hb_adid": "147ac541a",
    "hb_pb": "1.00"
  },
  "/9968336/header-bid-tag-2": {
    "hb_bidder": "appnexus",
    "hb_adid": "147ac541a",
    "hb_pb": "2.50",
    "hb_deal_appnexus": "ABC_123"
  }
}`

In this case we know rubicon was the highest bidder for slot /9968336/header-bid-tag-0 with a bid of $1.50

Comment: So even if some ad wins the auction DFP could still choose to display a different ad?

Comment: The choice yours you can setup your line items either way.